# The default value of buffer-local variable not set until first `setq`

Tags: elisp, variables, buffer-local

Say I define a buffer-local variable `foo`, and its default value is "a":

```
(defvar foo "a")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'foo)
(default-value 'foo) ;; => "a"
```

Immediately after this I run the following code:

```
(let ((foo "b"))
  (with-temp-buffer
    (message "foo: %s" foo))) ;; => "b"
```

The result is "b", which is the value I set in `let`.

Now if I use `setq` to set the variable, then rerun the exact same code as before:

```
(setq foo "c") ;; => "c"

(let ((foo "b"))
  (with-temp-buffer
    (message "foo: %s" foo))) ;; => "a"
```

The result is "a", which is the default value now.

**The question**: for a temporary buffer, the default value of `foo` is not set until I use `setq`? And as long as I don't use `setq`, I can use `let` to change the default value in other buffers?

**EDIT**: as @npostavs said, this is what `make-varible-buffer-local` really means. If I use `make-variable-buffer-local` myself, I can always use `setq` after that. But this becomes really tricky for the "built-in" buffer-local variables like `case-fold-search`. if I, as a package author, bind `case-fold-search` to `nil` in the outer `let`, and I want to use the default value (it might or might not be set by the user) in the `with-temp-buffer`, I have to use `setq` before `with-temp-buffer` to make sure the default value is actually being used in case the user doesn't have that `setq` in his/her `init.el`. For buffer-local variables, it probably means `setq` is always safer than `let` when we want to set the value. I wonder whether the design or the documentation could be improved.

Comment: If you put the let-bound portion inside the body of `with-temp-buffer` (instead of prior thereto), does that help any?  `with-temp-buffer` is a macro and it behaves a little differently than a standard function.  E.g., `(with-temp-buffer (let ((foo "b")) (message "foo: %s" foo)))`

Comment: @lawlist That should work as expected, which I understand. But I can't find any documentation explaining the example I said in the question.

Comment: I would probably ask the question -- How can I penetrate the body portion of a macro with a previously let-bound variable (e.g., with a back-tick/comma approach, or lexical-let, or perhaps something else)? ...  But, I don't want to hijack your question ... a macro maven should be along shortly to explain it all ... :)

Comment: @lawlist I don't know whether this is related to the macro. I actually test it locally using the expanded form of `with-temp-buffer` (that said, no macros). I think it is more like a specific behavior for buffer-local variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I, as a package author, bind `case-fold-search` to `nil` in the outer let, and I want to use the default value (it might or might not be set by the user) in the `with-temp-buffer`,

In this case I would recommend

```el
(let ((case-fold-search (progn (make-local-variable 'case-fold-search)
                               nil)))
  (with-temp-buffer
    ...))
```

---

The important thing to note here is that `make-variable-buffer-local` does not make a variable buffer-local!  It only arranges for it to become buffer-local **after it is set**.  You might want to use `make-local-variable` instead.

```
(make-variable-buffer-local VARIABLE)

Make VARIABLE become buffer-local whenever it is set.
```

The second thing to note is the interaction of `let` with buffer-local variables, from [`(elisp) Intro to Buffer-Local`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Intro-to-Buffer_002dLocal.html):

> *Warning:* When a variable has buffer-local bindings in one or more
>   buffers, `let` rebinds the binding that's currently in effect.  For
>   instance, if the current buffer has a buffer-local value, `let`
>   temporarily rebinds that.  If no buffer-local bindings are in effect,
>   `let` rebinds the default value.

So in the first case you **bind the global value** to `"b"` and that shows up in the temp buffer.  In the second case, after you have set the local value in `*scratch*` to `"c"`, you then **bind the local value** to `"b"`, but other buffers still see the global value of `"a"`.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the sentence `Make VARIABLE become buffer-local whenever it is set.`. I thought it was saying whenever we set the value, only the buffer-local value is set. So to avoid such a problem, we probably should always use `setq` immediately after `make-variable-buffer-local`?

Comment: I actually encounter this problem for "built-in" buffer-local variables like `case-fold-search` and `fill-column`. Emacs itself doesn't set them after it defines these buffer-local variables, and it requires user to set them in order to make them really buffer-local. Is this design intentional? I don't think most people aware of this.

Comment: Requiring the user to use `make-local-variable` or `setq` while it says this variable is a buffer-local is really confusing. But maybe that is another question regarding the design.

Comment: Well, if it was made immediately buffer local, then the question would be how to let-bind the default value at all...

Comment: Thanks. I still feel weird for using `make-local-variable` when I see the variable is already "buffer-local" from the manual. I would expect the `let` could bind the buffer-local copy. But this may be more suitable to be asked in Emacs-devel.

Comment: @npostavs letf on default-value might work in that case.

Comment: To make things more ..hmm.. interesting, some variables are always buffer-local without needing to `set` them (e.g. `default-directory`).  This is a messy part of Elisp's semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Like your proposed solution, we can  bind this to an arbitrary variable inside `let`, then change as you wish while remaining inside `let`, before reverting back to the original value.

The problem arises when changing buffer inside `let` - due to dynamic scoping, the value of local variables will not 'carry-over' into the new buffer, even when inside `lexical-let`.

Here's a function which checks for this problem and also sets and reverts the default value, which is the one used by a temporary buffer:

```
(defun f1 (VAR TEMP-VALUE) "
Sets VAR to TEMP-VALUE; works with local variables also." 
   (interactive)
   ;; starting value
   (insert (prin1-to-string VAR))
   (let ((var1 VAR))
     (setq VAR TEMP-VALUE)
     (when (local-variable-p 'VAR)
       (setq-default VAR TEMP-VALUE))
     ;; current buffer-local value
     (insert (prin1-to-string VAR))
     ;; value in new buffer
     (with-temp-buffer
       (message (prin1-to-string VAR)))
     ;; back to current buffer - unchanged
     (insert (prin1-to-string VAR))
     ;; revert
     (setq VAR var1)
     (when (local-variable-p 'VAR)
       (setq-default VAR var1))
   ;; back to original value
   (insert (prin1-to-string VAR)))
   ;; exit let and re-check
   (insert (prin1-to-string VAR)))
```

then

```
(f1 case-fold-search "xyz") --> t"xyz""xyz"tt
```

and "xyz" will appear in the `*Messages*` buffer.

Other local variables that come to mind in this context are `default-directory` and `uniquify-managed`...

In short, you could define a function like this and use it inside `let`, so save the hassle of checking whether the variable (symbol) is local or not:

```
(defun set-ld (SYM VAL) "set local (and default if applicable)"
       (interactive)
       (setq SYM VAL)
       (when (local-variable-p 'SYM)
     (setq-default SYM VAL)))
```